# Header files not found while installing VMWare tools in Kubuntu. Any idea why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, virtual-machine

I am using a Kubuntu image using VMWare.

In order to share files between the host and the guest OS. I need to install the VMWare tools as described [here](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/VMware/VMware%20Workstation/help/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=workstation_win/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html#1002344). However, when running the step

`./vmware-install.pl`

it triggers the following question

```
What is the location of the directory of C header files that match your running kernel?
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kubuntu, you need to install the Linux kernel headers using:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

If you haven't upgraded your packages yet, use the following to install the headers for the current loaded kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: (+1) Could be the `linux-headers-generic-pae` if it's a 32 bit VM

Comment: @Brian: I have already tried this. It is giving me the same message.